# How to find a sequence of generating elements in elementary abelian group to produce a given element?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

In many video games I have come across a following type of a puzzle. We are given $n$ levers or buttons and a set of indicators that are either on or off (say a grid with of either blue or red tiles or levers that are either pointing up or down) and these indicators are set in some start position $A$. Pulling a lever or pressing a button changes some indicators to the other position. Say pulling lever 1 moves levers 1,3 and n. If a lever is pointing up, next it points down or if a tile is red, it turns blue. The task is to press the buttons or pull the levers in correct order to reach some end state $E$, usually such that all indicators have the same value.

The puzzle can be expressed as problem of finding a sequence of elements in a given generating set of an elementary abelian group of order $n$ and exponent 2 whose sum with the given element $A$ produce the given element $E$.

Elementary abelian group is an abelian group in which every nontrivial element has the same order $p$, where $p \in \mathbb P.$ As $p = 2$, every nontrivial element is its own inverse. Clearly this is the case with the puzzle. Pulling a lever or pressing a button means adding the element represented by it to the current state, which is an element of the group too. Pulling the lever again simply adds the inverse of the original element, leaving the state unchanged. The order in which the levers are pulled clearly doesn't matter, as the group is abelian.

Say $n$ is 4. We have elements $\{\{1, 1, 1, 0\}, \{1, 0, 0, 1\}, \{0, 1, 0, 1\}, \{0, 0, 1, 1\}\}$. Say $A = \{0,0,0,0\}$ and $E = \{1,1,1,1\}.$ Then $\{0,0,0,0\}+\{0, 1, 0, 1\} + \{0, 0, 1, 1\}+\{1, 0, 0, 1\} = \{1,1,1,1\}.$

We can simplify this by using "canonical" elements $\{1,0,0,0\}, \{0,1,0,0\}$ and so on. If we label them $a,b,c$ and $d$, the generating set consists of $abc, ad, bd$ and $cd$
 and our solution sequence would be element $bdcdad = bcad = abcd.$ We need at least 3 additions.

Is there an algorithm or some other method for solving the puzzle and finding the combination in a general case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of regarding it as an abelian group of exponent 2, you want to think of it as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$.  Then what you're trying to do is to write a particular vector as a linear combination of basis vectors.

So go through your initial set of vectors, throwing out any that are linearly dependent on the previous ones.  This leaves you with a basis for the space of outcomes you can produce. Once you have a basis, just do a change of basis like you learned in linear algebra.

Comment: This extends well to cases where the indicators can have more than two states (suppose they are gears which can be in one of $3$ positions, and you need to line all the gears up in order to release the killer zombies!). Then it is similarly a vector space over $F_3$, etc.

Comment: Yep, in general an elementary abelian group of exponent $p$ has a natural $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space structure.  Although you may want to reconsider the wisdom of releasing killer zombies just because linear algebra provides you with the means to.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I was too exited about the group theoretical connotation to see the much simpler linear algebra interpretation. This does indeed work. I think throwing out vectors bit is unnecessery, as they already form a generating set, and I think that means they are linearly independent.

Comment: "As they already form a generating set, and I think that means they are linearly independent."  Not at all.  There's no guarantee that you have a spanning set or that you have a linearly independent set.  You could have both, either, or neither.

Comment: Can you provide a counter-example for this? I can't seem to think of one.

Comment: Just take a basis and add extraneous vectors to it.